# SWT Browser in eclipse and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, swing, swt

I made an simple browser in eclipse by SWT, and I want to execute javascript for downloading Youtube video; it works in chrome.

I tried with `browser.execute()`, but nothing happens; it should start downloading.

script:

```
javascript: isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/
false;
isIE ? swfHTML = document.getElementById('movie_player').getElementsByTagName('param')[1].value : swfHTML = document.getElementById("movie_player").getAttribute("flashvars");
w = swfHTML.split("&");
for (i = 0; i <= w.length - 1; i++) if (w[i].split("=")[0] == "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map") {
    links = unescape(w[i].split("=")[1]);
    break;
}
abc = links.split(",url=");
for (i = 0; i <= abc.length - 1; i++) {
    fmt = abc[i].split("|")[0];
    if ((fmt.indexOf("flv") > 0) && (fmt.indexOf("large") <= 0) && (fmt.indexOf("medium") <= 0)) {
        if (fmt.indexOf("rl=") > 0) {
            url = fmt.substring(4, fmt.indexOf("fallback_host") - 1);
            url = unescape(unescape(url));
            break;
        } else {
            url = fmt.substring(0, fmt.indexOf("fallback_host") - 1);
            url = unescape(unescape(url));
            break;
        }
    }
}
combineurl = url;
combineurl = combineurl + '&title=' + ((((document.title.replace('#', ' ')).replace('@', ' ')).replace('*', ' ')).replace('|', ' ')).replace(':', ' ');
window.location.href = combineurl.substring(0, 2000);
```

Comment: Reformatted by [`jsbeautifier`](http://jsbeautifier.org/).